# AutoComplete list is not showing same value but different in case for textbox control in VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, autocomplete

I am using below code to show the list in AutoComplete.

```
Dim gridTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
gridTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Normal
gridTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
gridTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
gridTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mAutocompleteLookupDescription.AutoCompleteSource
```

and the following line of code :

```
gridTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mAutocompleteLookupDescription.AutoCompleteSource
```

is giving me the correct list like

```
TEST1
test1
VALUE
value
```

but as soon as i am showing this in my gridview cell it's showing only once(means removing the duplicate value), means it's removing the duplicate value which different in case.

Is it Autocomplete restriction from microsoft?, 
if yes, can i have the link which proves this.

can we show the Duplicate value(like `VALUE` and `value`) in textbox Autocomplete?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: we can refer below links

[Autocomplete desc1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.85))

[Autocomplete desc2](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2012/09/18/windows-forms-how-to-create-an-auto-complete-text-box.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are duplicate entries in the maintained custom source of Autocomplete, automatic completion behaves unpredictably.
[image: Autocomplete behaviour]

helpful link for above text image
[Autocomplete desc1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletecustomsource%28v=vs.85%29)

[Autocomplete desc2](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2012/09/18/windows-forms-how-to-create-an-auto-complete-text-box.aspx)